# makefile: "no rule to make target 'arch/x86_64/Makefile'" linux kernel 2.2.0

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel

I'm trying to config my kernel (2.2.0) but when I use `make menuconfig` make says: `No rule to make target 'arch/x86_64/Makefile'`. It is a wrong response because there is no directory named `x86_64` in `arch`. Is there a problem with the kernel tree?

The source of my kernel tree can be found [here](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.2/)

Comment: You understand that 2.2.0 was released over 20 years ago?

Comment: @tripleee Doesn't matter. I want to config and compile it. Any help?

Comment: Does something that old even support 64-bit x86?

Comment: @Shawn I guess.

Comment: Yeah, looks like x86_64 was added in 2.5.5. You have to target i386 if you insist on using a stone-age kernel like 2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "problem" is that the `x86_64` architecture was not yet supported in 1999. You simply need to get a kernel from this millennium if you want to target this architecture, or painstakingly backport the necessary code changes to support it from a newer version.